# The synonyms of '雨后送伞'

Tags: idioms

The phrase '雨后送伞' means unnecessary assistance.

[释义]    比喻事后献殷勤。也比喻帮助不及时。

Is there better phrases or idiom to express such a context?

Comment: bkrs：雨后送伞 give an untimely help; come and offer to help when the work's all done; give sb. an umbrella after the rain is over，give belated help 同义: **事后诸葛亮, 放马后炮, 贼去关门**

Comment: @Tool why doesn’t this word work for you?

Comment: It's too plain not elegant @user3306356

Comment: FYI, Wiktionary has entries of [事后诸葛亮](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%8B%E5%BE%8C%E8%AB%B8%E8%91%9B%E4%BA%AE#Chinese) and [马后炮](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A6%AC%E5%BE%8C%E7%82%AE#Chinese), and search results for [贼去关门](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=贼去关门). But not [雨后送伞](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=雨后送伞) and [贼过兴兵](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=贼过兴兵). I don't mean that they are non-existent, but just to remind you of their popularity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

贼过兴兵

mobilize the troops after the bandits had gone

Meaning: fail to provide assistance timely; present unhelpful, useless, belated action